# How to make a data frame from different directories on R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, directory, subdirectory

I have set up my working directory which contains several folders with files in them. I would like to make a data frame with these files in each folder, however, the issue I am having is that using

```
list.files()
```

returns all of the names of the folders as strings (because it's looking at my working directory and just returning the names of the folders in them).

What I want to do is to get all of the files that is contained in each folder of the working directory and make a dataframe with all of it. Can anyone help? Let me know if my question doesn't make sense and I'd be happy to clarify!

Comment: Do all the df's have the same structure? Meaning, the same columns in the same order with the same names?

Comment: There aren't any data frames in the subdirectories; just different images that I'm looking to organize by year (the folders are by year).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
list.files(recursive = T)
```

It should display all files in all subdirectories, which I assume is what you want. Most functions in R have options like these, you can check them out in appropriate help files!

Sorry, I don't get what you mean by 'make a dataframe with all of it'. If you want a data frame with all the file names, you can use

```
as.data.frame(list.files(recursive = T))
```

If you want to import all these files as data frames and merge them together, you could use a loop with read.csv() function inside, or something of the like. Hard to elaborate without knowing the specifics.

Hope that was of help!

Comment: That was lots of help and did exactly what I wanted it to! Thank you so much :)